# Combine multiple rows, with distinct value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like below:

```
ID Date         Class     Level
1  2021/01/01    math      1
1  2021/01/01    english   1
1  2021/01/01    history   1
```

My current code:

```
grouped_df = df\
.groupby('ID','Date')\
.agg(collect_list('class').alias("class"),collect_list('level').alias("level"))\
.withColumn("class", concat_ws(", ", "class"))\
.withColumn("level", concat_ws(", ", "level"))
```

and the code give me output look like this:

```
    ID Date         Class                       Level
    1  2021/01/01    math, english,history      1, 1, 1
```

and because I want to make the combine row sort, I use `concat_ws`, but the order of class is not sorted by desire, is there any way to sort it when doing the `concat_ws()`? I want to combine `class` to sort alphabetically. like `English, history, math`. but when I do the `concat_ws`, the output can be `math_english,history,` or `history, math, English`.

Is there a way to make the output like below:

```
  ID Date        Class                       Level
  1  2021/01/01  english,history,math        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collect_set` to remove duplicates:

```
grouped_df = df\
    .groupby('ID','Date')\
    .agg(collect_list('class').alias("class"),collect_set('level').alias("level"))\
    .withColumn("class", concat_ws(", ", "class"))\
    .withColumn("level", concat_ws(", ", "level"))
```

If there is always only one single level, you can also consider grouping by the level as well, e.g.

```
grouped_df = df\
    .groupby('ID','Date', 'level')\
    .agg(collect_list('class').alias("class"))\
    .withColumn("class", concat_ws(", ", "class"))
```

Edit: if you want to sort the array, you can use `sort_array`:

```
grouped_df = df\
    .groupby('ID','Date')\
    .agg(sort_array(collect_list('class')).alias("class"),collect_set('level').alias("level"))\
    .withColumn("class", concat_ws(", ", "class"))\
    .withColumn("level", concat_ws(", ", "level"))
```

Comment: when doing the concat_ws, the combined row was not sorted, is there a way to sort it? for example, my combine row want to be alphabetic sort

Comment: @yokielove you can use `array_sort`

Comment: I have this error: NameError: name 'array_sort' is not defined, is there any import I need to add? I already import array

Comment: @yokielove you can `from pyspark.sql.functions import array_sort`

Comment: that also not work on my end, I have this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'array_sort'

Comment: @yokielove what's your spark version?

Comment: it is spark version 2.3.0.cloudera3 when i run it in the terminal

Comment: I see, array_sort wasn't supported in 2.3, so you can try the udf solution I added

Comment: @yokielove actually you can use `sort_array` from Spark, which is available starting from Spark 1.5

Answer (score 0):

To get unique values for `level` use `collect_set` and to order the `class` values you can't use `array_sort` with Spark 2.3, but you can use `collect_list` over an ordered window to get a sorted list instead of using UDF which generally leads to bad performances:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


w = Window.partitionBy("ID", "Date").orderBy("Class")

grouped_df = df.withColumn("Class", F.collect_list("Class").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("Level", F.collect_set("Level").over(w)) \
    .groupBy("ID", "Date") \
    .agg(
    F.concat_ws(",", F.max("Class")).alias("Class"),
    F.concat_ws(",", F.max("Level")).alias("Level")
)

grouped_df.show(truncate=False)

# +---+----------+--------------------+-----+
# |ID |Date      |Class               |Level|
# +---+----------+--------------------+-----+
# |1  |2021/01/01|english,history,math|1    |
# +---+----------+--------------------+-----+
```